# "No module" error when using Python's importlib in Django -- is the path at fault?

Tags: python, django

I'm doing something wrong with Python's `importlib` in my Django project, and can't figure it out.  I think there is a gotcha related to paths that I don't understand.

The simplest example illustrating the error occurs when I add these statements to my project's `views.py` file:

```
import test32                          # a file I created.  Is legal Python.
import importlib                       # Django is using Python 2.7
importlib.import_module                # confirms that the method exists
#importlib.import_module( 'test32' )
```

This works fine until I uncomment the last line.  Then I get an error:

```
ImportError at /

No module named test32

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:4321/
Django Version:     1.8
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

No module named test32

Exception Location:     /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py in import_module, line 37
Python Executable:  /Volumes/project663/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.3
Python Path:    

['/Volumes/project663/overall_project',
 '/Volumes/project663/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
 '/Volumes/project663/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/Volumes/project663/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg',
 '/Volumes/project663/lib/python27.zip',
 '/Volumes/project663/lib/python2.7',
 '/Volumes/project663/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Volumes/project663/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Volumes/project663/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Volumes/project663/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Volumes/project663/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/Volumes/project663/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Volumes/project663/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

I have tried numerous variants of the `import_module` statement, with dots preceding names, and using the `package` keyword, but none of them worked.  This method  can't be that hard to use, so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

What I really want to do is put `test32.py` in a subdirectory, but first I'd like to get it working in the same directory as `views.py`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is that while, in Python 2, you can still have a relative import using the

```
import test32
```

syntax, this won't work with `importlib`. The [`importlib` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/importlib.html) for Python 2.7 says:

> This module is a minor subset of what is available in the more
>   full-featured package of the same name from Python 3.1 that provides a
>   complete implementation of import. What is here has been provided to
>   help ease in  transitioning from 2.7 to 3.1.

I read that as `importlib` functioning much like Python3's `import`, where relative imports should be explicitly specified using the dot-syntax.

So something like:

```
importlib.import_module('.test32', 'full.app.path')
```

may work. Note the dot in front of 'test32', and I don't know your full app path, but it'll be something like 'projectname.appname' (basically, the imports used elsewhere in your Django project.

Comment: It worked!  My compliments on your keen reading of an obscure hint in the documentation.  The specific statement that works is: `importlib.import_module('.test32', 'appXX')` where `appXX` is the name of the Django *application* -- which, of course, is different than the Django *project*.